# How to remove duplicates from list

Tags: c++, stl

I have custom class Person which contains only data about person ( name, last name, height ...). I have couple lists of pointers to Person like

```
list<Person*> list1;
list<Person*> list3;
list<Person*> list2;
```

and I concatenate

using  `std::copy()` and `std::back_insert_iterator<std::list<Person*> >`

How to remove duplicates from list (only pointers which point to same junk of memory, not to delete that memory, only remove pointers from list) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind reordering the list:

```
list.sort()
list.unique()
```

Comment: This is an expensive way to do it IMO

Comment: @JBRWilkinson: this takes `O(n log n)` and AFAIK there is no faster way. Not to mention it only takes as much memory as used by the sorting algorithm.

Comment: @nightcracke: hash set (unordered_set) approach has O(N) average complexity, so "there is no faster way" only in worst case.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using a set rather than a list.